# Getting Transaction Declined for sale transaction

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, clover, clover-payment

We are working on an Apache Cordova plugin based on [remote-pay-android-go](https://github.com/clover/remote-pay-android-go) SDK that will allow Ionic/Cordova applications to integrate with the Clover Go device.

[Here](https://github.com/hotwax/cordova-plugin-clovergo) is the link to the plugin. We have implemented basic methods to init, connect, disconnect and make a sale. We are getting the error message "Transaction Declined. Please use another form for Payment" with reason "charge_declined", whenever we perform sale through the device.

I tried the [example](https://github.com/clover/remote-pay-android-go/tree/master/remote-pay-android-example-go) code in the [remote-pay-android-go](https://github.com/clover/remote-pay-android-go) SDK and the code gives the same error for sale from the device and works well for the manual transaction.

Can someone help me understanding where we may be missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get past this by following a recent [answer](https://community.clover.com/questions/22512/clover-go-charge-declined-error-on-sale-transactio.html) by David Marginian on the Clover forum.

```
I believe there is something going on with the gateway emulator on sandbox, we are looking into it. In the meantime try transactions > 50 dollars, they should go through fine.
```

I think as the default currency is set to cents, the values I tried always remained below 50 dollars.